# Using 3rd party C++ framework in Swift with Xcode 15 C++ Interoperability

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, module, frameworks

I have a precompiled 3rd party C++ framework (.framework folder) that I want to use in my Swift project with Xcode’s new C++ Interoperability instead of Obj-C bridging header.

I have added a „Modules“ subfolder to the .framework with a module.modulemap file containing the following:

```
framework module thirdPartyCppLib {
    umbrella header "CppPTSLClient.h"
    requires cplusplus
    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

The framework looks like this
[image: third party framework]

In my Xcode project, I changed „C++ and Objective-C Interoperability“ to „C++ / Objective-C++“ (in Build Settings - Swift Compiler Language) and imported the framework. It is visible in my target under „General - Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content“ as well as in „Build Phases - Embedded Frameworks“ and „Link Binary with Libraries“

When I try to import it for example in my ViewController.swift file, autocompletion will suggest it, but Xcode will throw an error „No such module“.

I’ve done the exact same thing with another 3rd party framework written in Obj-C and it’s well recognised.

I suppose there is some more things to configure for Swift C++ interoperability but I’m lost at the moment.

Any ideas?